# Making Data available offline in Progressive Web App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I [made a progressive web app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/) with [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev).

The user shall be able to make data available offline by clicking i.e. a button. Is there a convention or best practise to do that?

Comment: That's a *very* broad  and complex subject, not something that can be solved with conventions. This can be done using service workers and local storage BUT how and when are you going to sync the offline data? Do you check the cached data first or the server? Every application will have its own requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox). It's used in Create React App as well as Next.js.

The actual answer to the question can be found in section [Access Caches from Your Web App's Code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes#access_caches_from_your_web_apps_code).

Answer (score 4):

I have read this awesome documentation, that helps to make your PWA work offline

[Part 1](https://www.monterail.com/blog/pwa-working-offline)

[Part 2](https://www.monterail.com/blog/pwa-offline-dynamic-data)

Comment: Amazing links, thanks!